# ¿Como mostrar un dato de un archivo TXT consecutivamente en un Text View?

Tags: android, android-studio, archivo, kotlin, textview

Tengo un archivo txt con información (Datos) dentro de si, encapsulados mediante " ". De la siguiente forma:

```
"Dato uno"
"Dato dos"
"Dato tres"
...
"Dato N"
```

Entonces para leer la informacion utilizo:

```
val text:String
            val filename = "informacion.txt"
            val inputStream = resources.openRawResource(R.raw.informacion)
            var inputStreamReader: InputStreamReader = InputStreamReader(inputStream)
            var bufferedReader: BufferedReader = BufferedReader(inputStreamReader)
            text = bufferedReader.readLine().toString()
```

Y asi mismo la muestro en el TextView:

```
txtFrase?.setText(text)
```

Todo esto cada que se presiona un botón, pero al tocar el botón que llama todo esto, muestra solo el primer dato, vuelvo a presionar el botón y el mismo; Pretendo que cada que presione el botón se muestre el siguiente dato, se vuela a presionar y el siguiente
Desconozco como funcionan las clases BuferefReadere e inputStreamReader, por ende no sabría como implementarle un ciclo o algún contador, espero me puedan ayudar. Gracias.

Comment: simplemente agrega las lineas en una Array y los puedes acceder mediante su indice al dar clic a el botòn, agreguè respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Si tu archivo tiene pocas líneas puedes leer todas al principio y guardarlas en memoria. Luego simplemente almacenas el índice de la linea que estás mostrando y lo incrementas cada vez que presionas el botón

```
val lines = resources.openRawResource(R.raw.informacion).bufferedReader().readLines()
var currentLine = 0
txtFrase?.text = lines[0]
someButton.setOnClickListener {
    txtFrase?.text = lines.getOrElse(currentLine++) { "Fin de la lista" }
}
```

La otra opción es leer línea por línea. De esta forma no necesitas un contador pero tendrás que cerrar manualmente el reader cuando termines de usarlo

```
val reader = resources.openRawResource(R.raw.informacion).bufferedReader()
someButton.setOnClickListener {
    txtFrase?.text = reader.readLine() ?: "Fin de la lista"
}
```

Comment: no seria mejor solo leer la primera linea y despues hacer el proceso (guardar el indice y todo eso)?

Comment: Tiene aproximandamnte 300 lineas

Comment: ya completé mi respuesta. No necesitas guardar el índice para leer linea por línea

Comment: Okey, es que por un momento pense que era mucha carga en un arreglo

Comment: sí, en tu caso probablemente debas usar la segunda opción

Answer (score 1):

Primero define una variable que se incrementarà y obtendrà el valor de la linea en el archivo:

```
var contador : Int = 0;
```

cuando des clic al botòn usas el valor de la variable `contador` que serà usado como indice para obtener el valor en la linea del archivo, este valor se incrementarà , asì que cada vez que des clic al botòn se obtendrà la siguiente linea de tu archivo:

```
        val inputStream = resources.openRawResource(R.raw.informacion)

        val lineList = mutableListOf<String>()
        inputStream.bufferedReader().forEachLine { lineList.add(it) }
        text = lineList.elementAt(contador) //Obtiene valor de linea en archivo.
        contador++

        txtFrase?.setText(text)
```